# Click Java Button in URL with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to achive downloading table from company website. I can download first page. However, cannot jump to second page.

**HTML CODE for Page Number**

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$View$gv','Page$1')">1</a>
```

**HTML CODE**
[![HTML CODE FOR TABLE][1]][1]

page numbers are inside table and increasing one by one. at the first time when page one is active link href is not visible and shows as

```
<span>1</span>
```

I use below code to click page however I cannot succeded.

```
Set doc = ie.document

i = 0
For Each link In doc.Links
'doing downloading stuff here
i = i + 1
link.innerText = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$View$gv','Page$" & i
link.Click
Next
```

When I check the page also there is a javascript function.

**Javasript CODE**

```
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
```

after first page downloaded, macro click irrelevant page links even never click same page for each time.

**Extra Question**

also is there any way to get href values instead of innertext on below code

```
<a href="Link">User Name</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Open any page by parameter of the url:**
Look if you can open any page directly by a parameter of the url for the page number like this:
`https://yourUrl.com?page=2`

Then the walk through all pages is very easy. The only thing you must check at first is the number of the pages or a html code that only is in the page code when you try to open a page that is not available.

**How to get `href`**
You can't click `innertext`. That is only a string. You ask for a way to get the `href` and that is the right thought. If you want get the `href` of the first `a`-tag you can use this:

```
'Part of your code to open the page
'...
Dim nodeFirstLink as Object
Set nodeFirstLink = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
Debug.Print nodeFirstLink.href
'More of your code
'...
```

**Here is an example how to change the href**
But I don't know if this works also with JS links:

```
Sub ChangeHref()

  Dim htmlDoc As Object
  Dim nodeFirstLink As Object
  
  'Set a short HTML Document for this example
  Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("HtmlFile")
  htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = "<a href='https://amazon.com'>Amazon</a>"
  
  Set nodeFirstLink = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")(0) 'Get the first Link
  Debug.Print nodeFirstLink.outerhtml                      'The HTML of the first link in the html document
  Debug.Print nodeFirstLink.href                           'Only the href of the first link in the html document
  
  nodeFirstLink.href = "https://ebay.com" 'Changing the href in the first link
  Debug.Print nodeFirstLink.outerhtml     'The innertext is still Amazon
  Debug.Print nodeFirstLink.href          'The href is the new one
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. actually I give up becuase of no response of my post. page link is same for each page unless only java code is change in link. "<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$View$gv','Page$1')">1</a>" like 2,3,4... as you mentioned it is easy when link is changed.